# Tikz arrow which crosses multiple cells gets "covered up" by the table background color

Tags: tikz-pgf, tabularray

Please see the example code. If I remove the background color specification for odd rows, the arrow appears uninterrupted. Is there a way I can get the arrow to lay "on-top" of the background color? It shows correctly in the cell it begins in (which also has a background color), so I assume it has something to do with crossing into a new table cell.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{
    colspec = {Q[2in,l,m]X[1,c,m]X[0.7,c,m]X[1,c,m]X[1,c,m]X[0.7,c,m]X[1,c,m]},
    hlines,
    vlines,
    row{odd} = {bg=gray!50}, %if this is commented out, then the arrow displays uninterrupted
    row{1} = {bg=gray},
    row{even} = {bg=white}
}
 & Trial 1 & Units & {Sig Fig\\Check} & Trial 2 & Units & {Sig Fig\\Check} \\
 Mass of graduated cylinder BEFORE addition of sugar water & & & &\SetCell{r,h}\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]\node (end) at (0,0){*};\end{tikzpicture} & & \\
Mass of graduated cylinder AFTER addition of sugar water & \SetCell{c,h}\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]\node(start) at (0,0){*};\draw[->] (start.east) -- (end.west);\end{tikzpicture}& & & & & \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Shortly after me, someone posted this question which received some responses
[Tikz symbols over colors in table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/701257/tikz-symbols-over-colors-in-table)

In that question, the posted solution mentions the issue is with the coloring happening after the tikz drawing occurs (and that it is well known, but I couldn't seem to locate any similar stackexchange questions about it)

So I took almost all the original code and just moved the arrow drawing after the table was finished coloring since I could refer to the nodes and now it works perfectly.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{
    colspec = {Q[2in,l,m]X[1,c,m]X[0.7,c,m]X[1,c,m]X[1,c,m]X[0.7,c,m]X[1,c,m]},
    hlines,
    vlines,
    row{odd} = {bg=gray!50}, %if this is commented out, then the arrow displays uninterrupted
    row{1} = {bg=gray},
    row{even} = {bg=white}
}
 & Trial 1 & Units & {Sig Fig\\Check} & Trial 2 & Units & {Sig Fig\\Check} \\
 Mass of graduated cylinder BEFORE addition of sugar water & & & &\SetCell{r,h}\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]\node (end) at (0,0){*};\end{tikzpicture} & & \\
Mass of graduated cylinder AFTER addition of sugar water & \SetCell{c,h}\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]\node(start) at (0,0){*};\end{tikzpicture}& & & & & \\
\end{tblr}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw[->] (start.east) -- (end.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can `tikzmark` simplify a little your code?

Answer (score 0):

By use of the `tikzmark` library of `tikz` package is possible to write your code far more clear and short:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,   % <---
                tikzmark}      % <---
\tikzset{is/.style = {inner xsep=3pt, inner ysep=0pt}} % <---
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\noindent%
\begin{tblr}{cells = {font=\small},  % \small font size enable better formatting od cells contents
             colspec = {Q[1.5in,l, cmd=\RaggedRight] % <---
                        *{6}{X[c]}},
             colsep  = {3pt}, % <---
             row{1} = {m, font=\footnotesize\bfseries, bg=gray}, % <---
             row{odd} = {bg=gray!30},
             hlines, vlines,
            }
    & Trial 1   & Units & Sig Fig Check & Trial 2   & Units & Sig Fig Check \\
 Mass of graduated cylinder BEFORE addition of sugar water 
    &           &       &               & \tikzmarknode[is]{a}{$\ast$} % <---
                                                    &       &               \\
Mass of graduated cylinder AFTER addition of sugar water 
    & \tikzmarknode[is]{b}{$\ast$} % <---
                &       &               &           &       &               \\
\end{tblr}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw[->] (b.north east) -- (a.south west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

After at least tow compilation you will get the following result:

[image]